# delims tab not working for batch file

Tags: batch-file

Below query

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{CB708F54-6934-4636-8E3C-D10AD3A8231F} /v InstallLocation
```

returns

```
InstallLocation    REG_SZ    c:\Program Files (x86)\abcd\xyz\
```

i want to fetch `c:\Program Files (x86)\abcd\xyz\` i am not able to fetch i am using below command

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=    " %%a in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{CB708F54-6934-4636-8E3C-D10AD3A8231F} /v InstallLocation') do set ProductName=%%a
echo "%ProductName%"
```

i am getting only `c:\program`
please let me know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

you have split your string on white space and take only the third token, try to select all after the third :

```
for /f "tokens=3,* delims= " %%a in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{CB708F54-6934-4636-8E3C-D10AD3A8231F} /v InstallLocation') do set ProductName="%%a%%b"
```

Comment: @MC ND's answer will give you more infos (space is standard delim char so you dont have to specify it)

Comment: it works in windows 7, it is not working on windows xp

Comment: XP isnt supported anymore ;p  no sorry I dont have one to test.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your behaviour, for me (windows 7) `reg.exe` does not output tabs but spaces as separators.

The "correct" way of handling this case is to use any space/tab as delimiter (the default behaviour in `for /f`), discard the first token in the line (`InstallLocation` literal), retrieve the second token (`REG_SZ` literal) and a third token with *the remaining content in the line*.

```
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('
    reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{CB708F54-6934-4636-8E3C-D10AD3A8231F}" /v InstallLocation
') do set "ProductName=%%b"
echo "%ProductName%"
```